# Mediawiki media query wont take effect on browser resize when using firefox and IE

Tags: css, media

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=min-width, initial-scale=1.0">




@media (max-width: 455px) and (orientation: portrait) {

    #border-search {
  display: none;
}



#n-recentchanges {
visibility: hidden;
}   

#n-randompage {
display: none;
}

/*sidebar appearance*/

#column-one {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5B5B5B;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 0 1%;
    min-height: 149px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 90%;
    top: 5px;
    height: 1px;
    left: 6%;
    width: 15%;
}

#n-home {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -8px;
}

#n-sign-up {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px;
}

#n-help {
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    left: -4px;
}

#n-add-pix {
    position: relative;
    top: 19px;
    left: 0px;
}

#column-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5B5B5B;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 1%;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;  
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -10%;

}


#button .hidetext {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5B5B5B;
    display: block;
    color: #99D9EA;
    margin: 0 1%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0px;
    top: 95px;
    left: 53%;
}

#ca-edit {
    position: relative

}

/*edit page nav*/
.top_header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5B5B5B;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 1% 40px;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: -370px;
    left: -10%;
}
#p-cactions {
    float: left;
    display: none;

}

#p-cactions li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 35px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;

}

#p-personal {
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

.top_header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#p-cactions {
    float: left;
}

#p-personal li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

#column-content #bodyContent {
    color: #7b377b;
    float: left;
    font-size: 115%;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 50px;
    width: 94%;

}



#column-one h3 {
    display: none;
}

#column-one ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.mw-ui-vform-field {
width: 70%;
}

/*control font size*/

#column-one li {
  font-size: 18px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }



/*control special page layout*/   
.mw-ui-input {
    width:80%;
}

#wpLoginAttempt {
width: 70%;
}
.mw-submit {
width:70%;
}

/*control search input text color and font*/
#searchInput {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 4px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 400%;
    float: right;
    color: #99D9EA;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 92px;
    z-index: 3;

}

    .rectangle-box {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5B5B5B;
        float: right;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 1% 40px;
        position: relative; 
        width: 60%;
        height: 130px;
        left: 0%;
        top: 35px;
    }
    .rectangle-box2 {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5B5B5B;
        float: right;
        display: none;
        margin: 0 1% 0 40px;
        height: 400px;
        width: 70%;  
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: -10%;

}
}
```

The media query I'm using only seems to be recognized by Chrome and Opera. I'm trying to get my site to resize with this media query, but when I change the browser window to that size the query doesn't take effect. What can I do to fix this? Is there a problem with my code? What could cause this to happen only in certain browsers?

Comment: Is the page supposed to have no styling at all when it's less than 368px?

Comment: BSMP: yeah there is no device i need to accomadte smaller than that.

Comment: Dmitriy: added viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by changing the order of the media queries. They were blued out before in my coding panel. this went away by cutting and pasting the queries in a different order. Now the queries work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Change `viewport`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: tried but still same problem. it works in chrome, but only chrome. I checked firefox in the inspector and all i get is one media query but its for min width 501. its the only one that shows up.

Comment: just use `@media and (min-width: 368px)` only . Remove `(orientation: landscape) `

Comment: I need one for horizontal and one for for vertical. im doing this for tablets. also it doesnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have worked with media queries, I never used an *and*. And I'm sure the problem is caused by it. Remove it, and make it like this:

```
@media (min-width: 368px) {...}
```

The `and` will **not** come between `@media` and `(min-width: 368px)`, but it **will** come between the two ()s ie:

```
@media (min-width: 368px) and (orientation: landscape) {...}
```

**Edit:**

I'm currently on mobile so sorry I can't test code. But I think the correct query is `max-width`, not `min-width`. So just replace min-width with max-width.

Comment: What is your current media query?

Comment: Replace min-width with max-width

Comment: I tested it and the problem still occurs. I used the example link below from sabaeus which does work in firefox so i think its more of a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Mustaghees is correct. Remove that first "and".

Here's how it would look if you had an arbitrary background-color change when the browser size reaches `min-width:368px`:

http://codepen.io/sabaeus/pen/ZGOpPB?editors=110

Comment: your example works in my firefox browser so it may be some other issue.

Comment: i have removed the and as well which is why i think it may be some other issue.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Your post title was about the css not working in Firefox and IE. But if my example works in Firefox, then doesn't that mean the issue is resolved?

Comment: no its not because the website the code is for wont work. when the browser is resized. im using mediawiki which is more than pure css.

Comment: Please edit the original post to say that you're using mediawiki. Also, please include a link to a codepen/jspaddle/live site that shows how things look for you.

Comment: I was able to look at it once before getting a redirect loop. And it's def not this, but I did notice a stray `?php>` up at the very top left.

Comment: yeah thats an error i need to fix. im not launching yet. Its on the list but not highest.

Comment: thats odd that you got a redirect loop. I had somone do work o it and it worked for them. also works on tablet mobile and my computer.